# Unable to install GWT plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install GWT plugin for Eclipse, I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2022-09.

I am unable to perform the install via every method and I get this error message :

```
  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.   Software being installed: GWT 2.8.1 SDK
    2.8.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt28.feature.feature.group
    2.8.0.201710131939)   Missing requirement: GWT Eclipse Platform Plugin 3.0.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform 3.0.0.201710131939) requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.servlet 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: GWT 2.8.1 SDK 2.8.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt28.feature.feature.group
    2.8.0.201710131939)
        To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt28 [2.8.0.201710131939,2.8.0.201710131939]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: GWT Development Tools Core Plugin 3.0.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.core 3.0.0.201710131939)
        To: osgi.bundle; com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.platform 0.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: GWT Eclipse Plugin 3.0.0.201710131939 (com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core 3.0.0.201710131939)
        To: osgi.bundle; com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.core 0.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt28 2.8.0.201710131939
        To: osgi.bundle; com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core 0.0.0
```

To my understading I am missing depencies but I cannot find a way to install them.

I think it comes down to this :

```
'osgi.bundle; javax.servlet 0.0.0'
```

How can I resolve theses errors ?

Comment: Having the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No I haven't been able to find a solution

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse releases beginning with 2022-06 do not contain the javax.servlet bundle anymore. Add the 2022-03 release as available software site. Go to "preferences/install/update/available software sites" and add the following URI https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03. Now try again and it should work.

Comment: With Eclipse 2023-12 the problem is not solved yet, but your answer still is working